# Markov Memoryless Property confusion with counterexample

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Consider the following transitions:

[image]

$$P(X_2=d|X_1=b)=P(X_1=d|X_0=b)=3/4$$

By Markov property, all what happened before $X_1=b$ doesn't matter:

So when I see $P(X_2=d|X_1=b)$ I know that I can choose $X_0$ in all possible ways.

$$P(X_2=d|X_1=b)=P(X_2=d|X_1=b,X_0=a) + P(X_2=d|X_1=b,X_0=b)=$$
$$P(X_2=d|X_1=b)=1*2/3*3/4+1*1/4*3/4=11/16$$
$$\ne P(X_1=d|X_0=b)$$

Did I actually give a counterexample or what am I confusing here ?

Comment: What is the counterexample for?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy does it satisfiy the markov property ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property

Comment: Any stochastic matrix gives rise to a Markov chain.

Comment: Any stochastic matrix gives rise to a homogeneous Markov chain with that transition matrix. Please check your calculation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $X_1=b$, it's true that $X_0$ must have been either $a$ or $b$. However, there's no rule that allows you to write
$$
P(X_2=d\mid X_1=b)=P(X_2=d\mid X_1=b,X_0=a) + P(X_2=d\mid X_1=b,X_0=b).\tag1
$$
Indeed, by the Markov property, the RHS of (1) is two copies of the LHS, which is impossible.

The second mistake that you made was in the evaluation $P(X_2=d\mid X_1=b,X_0=a)$. You evaluated $P(X_2=d, X_1=b\mid X_0=a)$ instead.

Comment: could you please clarify how to evaluate $P(X_2=d\mid X_1=b,X_0=a)$ correctly then ?

Comment: @Oleg Given that we are observing a Markov chain, the probability $P(X_2=d\mid X_1=b,X_0=a)$ equals $P(X_2=d\mid X_1=b)$ by the Markov property. You can then read off the answer $\frac34$ from the transition diagram. That's the only way to evaluate the probability given the information you have.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X_2=d|X_1=b)=P(X_1=d|X_0=b)=3/4$ is not a statement for the Markov Property.

Suppose I tell you that at the current time-step, you're in a given state. This information is sufficient for you to calculate the probabilities of being in different states at the next time-step. Hence, the process is Markov.

In your case, the statement for Markovness would be:
$P(X_2=d|X_1=b)=P(X_2=d|X_1=b,X_0=a)=P(X_2=d|X_1=b,X_0=b)$

Let me know if something is still unclear. I'll be happy to clarify :)

Comment: for the expression $P(X_2=d|X_1=b,X_0=d)$ aren't you conditioning on something which is impossible ? 

given that I'm at $d$ at $t=0$, I couldn't have moved to $b$ at $t=1$

Comment: Sorry, got the arrows wrong. I'll correct the mistake but I hope your question is answered?

Comment: Almost, I just found this interesting property $P(X_n = j | X_0 = i) = P(X_{n+s}=j | X_s=i)$ and that's why I wrote the 
$P(X_2=d|X_1=b)=P(X_1=d|X_0=b)=3/4$

Comment: That doesn't seem like a general property of a Markov process. It is assuming some sort of translational invariance in the process which is absent in our problem.
As an example, the property that you mention will hold for a random walk on the integer line (1D lattice).